# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a app with several other people and today I pulled master and all of a sudden while building I'm receiving an error:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.

Another colleague is also running into this issue, but several other developers are not having this issue. We're all running the same tsconfig.json.

I've updated TypeScript and we're all running Node v10+.

What could cause the discrepancy between our systems?

Comment: `boolean` is not assignable to `false`, because `boolean` is equivalent to `true | false`.

Comment: Can you update you answer to include some code that shows the issue? That might make it easier for us to see what's going on.

Comment: That's not the question though. The question is that this code compiles on pc a but not on pc b.

Comment: Yes, I know. But without knowing what doesn't compile, it's kinda hard to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Probably a different version of TypeScript (updated TypeScript => yours was too new). Was the TypeScript toolchain part of your lockfile?

Answer (score 6):

I can't explain why there is such discrepancy. But the solution that helped me was to use `false as const` instead of boolean variable or simple `false`.

---

The TypeScript handbook explains `as const` as ["Literal Inference"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference).

Comment: Thank you.  This answered my question.  This is what makes TypeScript types so frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wrote accidentaly something like

```
interface StateFlagsProps {
    flags: FlagProps[],
    isVerbose: false,
}
```

instead of

```
interface StateFlagsProps {
    flags: FlagProps[],
    isVerbose: boolean,
}
```